# How to use Japanese characters for a single page

Tags: css, encoding

I've been asked to produce a single page on a client's Wordpress site that has a Japanese translation of key paragraphs from the site.

The straight copy and paste from the translated text in a Word doc produced mostly accurate results but occasionally I get these characters ます and a few others replaced by

[image: non-rendered character]

I've been told that the font I'm using likely doesn't have the characters. I then looked for a common Japanese font stack (found in SO):

font-family:"ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro",Osaka, "メイリオ", Meiryo, "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", "MS PGothic", sans-serif;

and tried applying it inline and in the stylesheet but with no joy. How do I apply it to my site? Is it being applied but I need to change region/language? Why can I seem to paste the characters successfully into every other wysiwyg and document?

I've also changed the character encoding throughout my db to UTF8.

Would be really grateful for some help with this!

Thanks, Steve

Update: Thanks Goleztrol and Worm for the quick replies. Just discovered that the Wordpress WysiWyg seems to be the problem. Pasting ます above or below the_content(); works just fine

Answer (score 0):

never ever copy text from word document into anything web related. Word documents contain extra styling information which might break the content that you try to copy. If you need to copy test it is best to receive it as a simple text file that can be opened in notepad.

Comment: Yep, I pasted it into Sublime first to remove the styling